# Creating folders and new *.xlsx file with macro from template like xlsm file

Tags: vba, excel, mkdir

I have this code that **creates a folder and a saves the actual file in it, but i want that it only saves a copy with only one sheet in it**. So that the file with the code works like a template...

You write your stuff and press the button and it saves an .xlsx file with one sheet (the sheet with the form) in the new created folder... so you could do this with hundreds of files an folders.

So in the end it should work like this:

1. You open the .xlsm file where the code below is in.
2. You got to sheets one FORM (what should be "exported" later on) and
   a list where you copy stuff in the form.
3. When you filled the form and press the button and it saves the Form
   sheet in the new folder as .xlsx and you can continue in the .xlsm
   file.

If it's unclear for you please ask.

The code i have now

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim strFilename, strDirname, strPathname, strDefpath As String
On Error Resume Next ' If directory exist goto next line
strDirname = Range("D81").Value ' New directory name

strFilename = Range("D8").Value 'New file name
strDefpath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path 'Default path name
If IsEmpty(strDirname) Then Exit Sub
If IsEmpty(strFilename) Then Exit Sub

MkDir strDefpath & "\" & strDirname
strPathname = strDefpath & "\" & strDirname & "\" & strFilename 'create total string

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strPathname & ".xlsm", _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Problem here is i have Names for the forms that are like 1102,1103 an going on like that. the next step is that there are files with the name 1102_1 and 1102_2 and they both should go in the folder 1102 ...

It's a bit out of my knownledge please help me guys :) greets

Now i am using this code below
Problem is that it always closes the `xlsm` file what really annoyes and when i reopen it it wants to update the file i need to remove that but i don't know how :/... and it only should export/save one special sheet

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim strFilename As String, _
strDirname As String, _
strPathname As String, _
strDefpath As String, _
SheetToExport As String, _
WbMaster As Workbook, _
WbCopy As Workbook


On Error Resume Next ' If directory exist goto next line
strDirname = Range("W12").Value ' New directory name
strFilename = Range("D8").Value 'New file name

Set WbMaster = Application.ActiveWorkbook
SheetToExport = Range("A1").Value 'Or specify UserForm output

strDefpath = WbMaster.Path 'Default path name

If IsEmpty(strDirname) Then Exit Sub
If IsEmpty(strFilename) Then Exit Sub

MkDir strDefpath & "\" & strDirname
strPathname = strDefpath & "\" & strDirname & "\" & strFilename 'create total string

WbMaster.Sheets(SheetToExport).Copy
Set WbCopy = Application.ActiveWorkbook

WbCopy.SaveAs Filename:=strPathname & ".xlsx", _
                FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
                ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

WbCopy.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Yo can create with one XLSM file as many XLSX files as you wish. Yet, saving the macro in the new XLSX is not possible.

Comment: @Balinti: I don't see Swi asking for a solution where a macro is saved in an XLSX file. But I am also a bit hazy as to what he/she wants. In the title is `.xls` which would indicate that old Excel file formats should be created. At the same time the code suggests to save the new workbooks as `.xlsm`. So, what is it now?

Comment: @Balinti do you have an idea how i can stop it from closing itself?

Comment: After the saving as you can activate the xlsm once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful on your variable declaration!

The way you did it in your OP (original post) :

`strFilename`, `strDirname` and `strPathname` are declared as `Variant` and not as `String`.

You can still use them BUT it'll take much more memory and can be issue if you use them as arguments.

---

See the code :

```
Dim strFilename As String, _
    strDirname As String, _
    strPathname As String, _
    strDefpath As String, _
    SheetToExport As String, _
    WbMaster As Workbook, _
    WbCopy As Workbook


On Error Resume Next ' If directory exist goto next line
strDirname = Range("D81").Value ' New directory name
strFilename = Range("D8").Value 'New file name

Set WbMaster = Application.ActiveWorkbook
SheetToExport = Range("A1").Value 'Or specify UserForm output

strDefpath = WbMaster.Path 'Default path name

If IsEmpty(strDirname) Then Exit Sub
If IsEmpty(strFilename) Then Exit Sub

MkDir strDefpath & "\" & strDirname
strPathname = strDefpath & "\" & strDirname & "\" & strFilename 'create total string

WbMaster.Sheets(SheetToExport).Copy
Set WbCopy = Application.ActiveWorkbook

WbCopy.SaveAs Filename:=strPathname & ".xlsx", _
                FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
                ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

ClosingWb = MsgBox("Do you wish to close the exported file?",vbYesNo,"Close exported file")
If ClosingWb <> vbNo Then WbCopy.Close
```

Comment: What does this do? `SheetToExport = Range("A1").Value 'Or specify UserForm output`

Comment: At first thank you really much, i appreciate that. 
It works almost perfectly, the problem that i have is that it exports all sheets, it only should export the one sheet, the form/template.. how to :o

Comment: I don't want that it always closes the file.... how can i stop that?
And when i reopen the `.xlsm` file it asks me every time if i want to update, how can i stop this to?

Comment: 1. `SheetToExport = Range("A1").Value` is to specify where you are going to take the information (the name of the sheet you want to export)
2. It should export only the sheet that you name in the argument `SheetToExport`
3. See edit for closing file or not
4. For links update, it depends what you exported, if the sheet that you copy has formulas in it, you should add `WbCopy.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy : WbCopy.Sheets(1).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` before saving. And if you want to turn the notifications off, just google it, you'll find (I don't remember how to do it)

Comment: Thank you really much everything works great now! wunderful!

Comment: There is only one question left. In the exportet file the button stays, how can i not save the button?
(The button also exports kind of..)

Comment: after you copy the sheet, and before you save the book, wbcopy.oleobjects (buttonname).delete